# How to specify implemented Service Contract dll in WCF config

Tags: wcf, wcf-configuration, wcf-endpoint

My service implementation is present in `Calc.dll`.

WCF Service is present in `Svc.dll`

I have added contract inside endpoint tag in the WCF `app.config` file of `Svc.dll`.

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="MySvc">
   <endpoint contract="Company.ICalc" .... />
```

How does WCF know that the service is implemented in `Calc.dll`? We have just specified the contract name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for this to work, your `svc.dll` project must somehow reference `calc.dll` - and thus, the .NET / WCF runtime can find the specified namespace and class.